# Apply backgroundColor and elevation/shadow only to FlatList's items container (excluding the header)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I need the `backgroundColor` and `elevation`/`shadow*` to be applied only to the `FlatList`'s items container, not the header. If the `FlatList` style has `elevation` set, the shadow will be at the borders of the entire list: items and header as a whole, but I need it to be at the borders if the items container only. Is this possible or is there any trick to achieve this?

Comment: Apply those styles to the top level component created in your `renderItem`

Answer (score 4):

you need to apply desired styles to the items themselves, not to the FlatList component:

```
<FlatList
      data={[{ name: 'item1' },{ name: 'item2' },{ name: 'item3' }]}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}`}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <View
          style={{
            shadowColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 3,
              height: 3,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.5,
            shadowRadius: 5,
            elevation: 2,
            backgroundColor: 'white',

            padding: 10,
            margin: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Text>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
        </View>
      }
    />
```

use FlatList's [contentContainerStyle](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) prop to add some padding inside FlatList so that items don't have their shadow cut off by FlatList's boundaries